# Read from dict which is a list of dict in python

Tags: python

I want to check conditions of key values in a python dict. My dict is a json response which would look like this:

```
result = {'arc': [{'empid':'S45',
                   'empname':'abc',
                   'empage':45,
                   'status':0,
                   'location': 'USA'},
                  {'empid':'S46',
                   'empname':'xyz',
                   'empage':34,
                   'status':1,
                   'location': 'USA'},
                  {'empid':'S47',
                   'empname':'oop',
                   'empage':36,
                   'status':1,
                   'location': 'UAE'}
                 ]}
```

I want to check the 'status' value and replace it as 'deactivate' if its 0. And this to be performed for 'location': 'USA' only.

Here is what I came with:

```
data = result.values()
for i in data:
    for dict in i:
        for item in dict.values():
            print(item)
```

Please help on how to check the condition by iterating over every key:value pair.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to iterate over each element of the dict in `result['arc']`, then if the status is `0` and location is `USA` replace the element with `'deactivate'`.

```py
for e in result['arc']:
    if e['location'] == 'USA' and e['status'] == 0:
        e['status'] = 'deactivate'
        
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The list you want to iterate over is not `result.values()`, it's `result['arc']`. And you don't need to iterate over the values in the dictionaries.

```
for arc in result['arc']:
    if arc['location'] == 'USA' and arc['status'] == 0:
        arc['status'] = 'deactivate'
```

Also, don't use `dict` or `list` as variable names, it replaces the built-in functions with those names.